# How to stay on the same on viewcontroller and keep the data after minimizing my xamarin.ios app?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, viewcontroller

I tried to minimize and make my app run in the background  , but apparently the app starts from the first `ViewController` all over again every time  I go back to the application . Is there anyway to keep the same data and `ViewController` that I left from?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the app goes to the background it is restored in the same state (same viewcontroller) unless:

- it is terminated by the operating system to free the memory
- your app has some logic that activates something else in that case

In the first case there is not much that you can do - obviously you can buy a device that has more memory, avoid running apps that use a lot of memory while your app is in the background, try to make your app require less memory.

In the second case you should know what is happening as it is your code, but if you don't know try to add the `ViewWillDisappear` and see what activates it in debugger.

Comment: I was using ```UIApplication.Notifications.ObserveWillEnterForeground
```for checking if the user already logged in inside the login ViewController . Thanks for telling me about ```ViewwillDisappear```